# Programmatically add WooCommerce Analytics advanced filter

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I'm struggling to programmatically add an advanced orders filter to Woo Analytics. The filter will be based on the value of a specific postmeta. So the filter will either show orders with a specific value on a specific postmeta, or show all the rest orders (with any other value than that on the same postmeta).

So far I did the JS part:

```
wp && wp.hooks && wp.hooks.addFilter('woocommerce_admin_orders_report_advanced_filters', 'add-advanced-filter', function (advancedFilters) {
    advancedFilters.filters['marketplace_orders'] = {
        labels: {
            add: 'Order Types',
            remove: 'Remove Marketplace orders filter',
            rule: 'Select Marketplace orders filter',
            title: '{{title}}Show orders{{/title}} {{filter /}}',
            filter: 'Select type of orders to show'
        },
        input: {
            component: 'SelectControl',
            options: [
                {
                    value: 'all',
                    label: 'All',
                },
                {
                    value: 'marketplace',
                    label: 'Marketplace only',
                },
                {
                    value: 'not_marketplace',
                    label: 'All but Marketplace'
                },
            ],
            defaultOption: 'all'
        }
    };

    return advancedFilters;
});
```

The above code creates an interface result like this:

[image]

[image]

I can't figure out how to go from there though. Obviously this is not enough, but I'm not sure what the next step is. Any guide I found (there are no more than 2-3 ones on the subject) are not very clear and are not even marked as solved... The closer I found is [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-advanced-filters/) (which is based on woocommerce-admin which is a dead project anyway).

Anyone had any luck with adding such a filter?